# Hudson git error ssh

Tags: git, ssh, continuous-integration, hudson

If there is anyone that can help me understand why this git repo isn't cloning that would be   amazing.

I runt the same command from the terminal it works. I hoping to find out where I can put the password so the server can authenticate the connection.

Please and thank you.

```
ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin' : Could not clone ssh://build@kdmanalytics.net/usr/local/repository/kdm/git/TestCaseGenerator.git
ERROR: Cause: Error performing /usr/bin/git clone -o origin ssh://build@kdmanalytics.net/usr/local/repository/kdm/git/TestCaseGenerator.git /var/lib/hudson/jobs/KDM_Test_Case_Generator/workspace
Command returned status code 128: Initialized empty Git repository in /var/lib/hudson/jobs/KDM_Test_Case_Generator/workspace/.git/
No protocol specified

(ssh-askpass:12523): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: :0.0
Host key verification failed.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

Trying next repository
ERROR: Could not clone repository
FATAL: Could not clone
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Could not clone
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM$2.invoke(GitSCM.java:719)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM$2.invoke(GitSCM.java:658)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:753)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:735)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:658)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1046)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.checkout(AbstractBuild.java:479)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.run(AbstractBuild.java:411)
    at hudson.model.Run.run(Run.java:1248)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:46)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:129)
```

Comment: did you run it as hudson from the terminal or as yourself?

Comment: Hudson cannot establish a ssh connection because your key is protected by a password.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should setup a ssh trust relationship between your repo and the git server.

You only need to do this once.

In short it goes qs follows :

Log in as the user running hudson

```
ssh-keygen
```

use an empty password

This creates 2 files in .ssh : id_dsa and id_dsa.pub.

```
cat .ssh/id_dsa.pub
```

Now copy the gibberish representing the public key.

```
ssh repo-server
```

Confirm you want to add the host key to known_hosts. Log in using the account accessing the repo.

```
cat - >>.ssh/authorized_keys
```

(double check you have 2 >'s or risk the wrath of your colleagues)
Then paste the gibberish you just copied.

Log out and verify you can now ssh without having to provide a password.

This works for Unix based hosts. For github, gitosis, windows the process is similar, but of course different.

Hudson should now be able to connect.

Comment: Thank you!  I had been struggling for awhile not understanding why my SSH key wasn't working, until I read your instructions, specifically the line "Log in as the user running hundson" :-)

Answer (score 0):

Should that url be:

```
ssh://build@kdmanalytics.net:/usr/local/repository/kdm/git/TestCaseGenerator.git
```

?

(Missing colon after the ".net")

Comment: If you provide which protocol to use "explicitly", ':' is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check the following:

1. You are using ssh keys of the user who ran hudson daemon. For example, if user=hudson, then you should log on as hudson and generate ssh keys
2. You have loaded your public key to your server (github, assembla) from correct `.ssh/id_rsa.pub` file i.e. for the same user who ran hudson daemon
3. You have added RSA fingerprint of your server to your `.ssh/known_hosts` file

Answer (score 0):

If all should be right but it's strangly not working, make sure your project is rally build on the slave you configured.