# hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Could not fetch from any repository

Tags: github, maven-2, hudson

I want to configure hudson+git and want to create a build. But I am getting following exception:

```
Started by user nitish
Checkout:workspace / /root/.hudson/jobs/NightlyGit/workspace - hudson.remoting.LocalChannel@dd7efd
Using strategy: Default
Checkout:workspace / /root/.hudson/jobs/NightlyGit/workspace - hudson.remoting.LocalChannel@dd7efd
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
Fetching upstream changes from https://github.com/test/eng.git
ERROR: Problem fetching from origin / origin - could be unavailable. Continuing anyway
ERROR:  (Underlying report) : Error performing command: /usr/bin/git fetch -t https://github.com/test/eng.git +refs/heads/nightly:refs/remotes/origin/nightly
Command "/usr/bin/git fetch -t https://github.com/test/engile.git +refs/heads/nightly:refs/remotes/origin/nightly" returned status code 128: error: The requested URL returned error: 401 while accessing https://github.com/test/eng.git/info/refs

fatal: HTTP request failed

ERROR: Could not fetch from any repository
FATAL: Could not fetch from any repository
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Could not fetch from any repository
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM$3.invoke(GitSCM.java:887)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM$3.invoke(GitSCM.java:845)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:758)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:740)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.gerRevisionToBuild(GitSCM.java:845)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:622)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1483)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.checkout(AbstractBuild.java:507)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.run(AbstractBuild.java:424)
    at hudson.model.Run.run(Run.java:1366)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:46)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:145)
```

I am newbie to the git ,I dont know what is the exact problem is there any creadentials required while using git with hudson?. Right now I have created the hudson job and providing the git repository link but it throws above exception. can somebody help me to sort out this issue.

Comment: What version of hudson and the git plugin are you using?

Comment: Hudson git plugin is 2.2.0 and hudson version is 2.3.6

Comment: I am following the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3516719/hudson-git-error-ssh but don't understand Log in as the user running hudson

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have created the SSH key on hudson server and added it to my github account that solved my issue.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

1. Go to the job's "**Configure**" page.
2. Under **Source Code Management** → **Git** → **Additional Behaviors**, add a behavior "**Wipe out repository & force clone**":

[image]

[image]

3. Click on **Save** button.
4. Try to **Build** again.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the permission of the workspace also can cause the same error.

```
sudo chown -R jenkins: <workspace>
```